# Please explain rails has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to understand rails associations

I've the following tables and I've to define their relations, can any one please help me understand.
The tables are Products, ProductDistributors, and Distributors.
Every product has a distributor, a distributor carries multiple products

I defined these as

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :product_distributor
   has_one  :distributor, through: :product_distributor
end
class ProductDistributor < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :products
   belongs_to :distributors   
end
class Distributor < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_distributors
   has_many :products, through: :product_distributors
end
```

Is this correct? If not, how can I correct it?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the problem lies in the `Distributors` class name because it's plural.  when you say something like `has_many :distributors`, Rails by default will link to the `Distributor` class, but in your case the class name is `Distributors`.

Adding `class_name` option to your relationship declarations should work:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :product_distributor
   has_one  :distributor, through: :product_distributor, class_name: 'Distributors'
end
class ProductDistributor < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :product
   belongs_to :distributor, class_name: 'Distributors' 
end
class Distributors < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :product_distributors
   has_many :products, through: :product_distributors
end
```

Also note that your `belongs_to` should be singular not plural.  Please go through the Association guide for details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html.

Comment: Thanks Vinod for answering. The "Distributors" class name was a typo I made in stackoverflow. Sorry about that.

Comment: @user2056101, It happens!  I think you still need to fix the `belongs_to` declarations, your `belongs_to :products` and `belongs_to :distributor` should be singular not plural as sown in the answer.  You can ignore the `class_name` since you've corrected your model name.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, Product has one (belongs to) Distributor, and Distributor has many Products. So you not need to use ProductDistributor

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :distributor
end

class Distributors < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

Just add column *distributor_id* to *products* table

I recomend you to read [Active Record Associations Guid](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to understand associations

Comment: Thanks for answering. I cannot alter the product table to include distributor_id. That is the reason why I've the product_distributor. i.e., I need to be able to access distributor from product like product.distributor, however, I do not and cannot alter product table.

Answer (score 0):

The reason to use `has_many through:` is that you need to use a join table that isn't named in the standard Rails naming convention.  In this case, ProductDistributor has such a table associated (product_distributors) because the Rails convention puts the tables in the name in lexicographic order and pluralizes them.  The Rails table name would be `distributors_products`.  If you created such a table with foreign keys to the ids of the `distributors` and `products` tables you wouldn't need to specify the join table and you could just say `has_and_belongs_to_many :distributors` on Products and `has_and_belongs_to_many :products` on Distributors.

What you have isn't quite right for what you are trying accomplish, frankly.  You have a many_to_many relationship between Product and Distributors.  If you really want a many_to_one relationship between Product and Distributor you should make the following changes:

schema changes: Drop the product_distributors table and add a foreign key from products to distributors.

```
drop_table :product_distributors
change_table :products do |t|
  t.references :distributors
end
```

model changes: Delete the model for ProductDistributor and change Product and Distributor to  reference each other directly.  Also note that Distributors is renamed to Distributor.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to  :distributor
end

class Distributor < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :products
end
```

Comment: Thanks Sean for answering. I can't change the product table. i.e. it is not acceptable to have distributor_id in the products table. When we add t.reference :distributors, it adds distributor_id to products table. Essentially, I want the convenience referencing mechanism the model provides, but cant change the schema much except that I can add a new table distributor_products.